# iOS : How to implement a bookmark for ePub reader?

Tags: objective-c, ios, bookmarks, epub

I'm create an ePub reader for iPad/iPhone

The basic code is from [AePubReader](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader)

I add page curl effect,adjust image size ... but remove some function (ex.slider the page)

But I still don't know how to implement bookmark function ...

We have many [discussion here](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader/issues/5)  , some people record the page number as bookmark index

This is a solution , but not good enough , if you wanna add mark in page 100 .

When you change the text size , you may not found the paragraph you want in p.100

So , as I say in the issue discuss , I need to do few things ...

1.Set < p >  tag or id

2.Get the < p > in  every page

3.Press the bookmark button means record the top < P > in current page ,if the the top < P > is from previous page , record the previous page's last < P >

4.Search the < P > by tag ,  if match , show the page number .

So ... I hope someone know the answer , Because Apple do not release any ePub reader

Thanks for any reply or answer .

Webber

Comment: Is it help if I use Apple Technology support ???

Comment: actually iBooks does have, it can read epub books.

Comment: I know ibook is an epub reader , don't you wish to implement a open epub reader for object-c ???

Comment: I have just developing ePub client using Java.

Comment: Ha , I only use search method in JAVA .

Comment: @WebberLai can you help me with some piece of code, I'm trying to implement the same(epub reader with page - based application like in iBook) and it's kind of difficult to me doing that...

Answer (score 1):

This is might be one of solution ,when you load a part of epub , in typical situation ,one chapter could be just one html file .

We pagination the chapter in webView , so we got the the location of the html file we just reading , ex 35% part at the html .

so if we adjust the accuracy , like 0.2674 % at html location.

You can find where is the bookmark location ...

please vote the answer if you think this is right .

Comment: I share an old version , but not good ...So I will find some day to create a new one

Comment: Thanks sir,I am Waiting for your new code,and thanks for helping in a critical situation

Comment: Could you update the code sir. i verified but still presenting the same code otherwise please mail the code prasanna.d@greatinnovus.com

Comment: @dineshprasanna it's not ready yet ...I have some issue when open picture epub books

Comment: thanx for ur reply sir. Can you share the code with me, let me also try and if it gets positive i will share it with you....

Comment: i've been developing an epub reader for like 1 month. I've implemented all the functionalities. What am not still able to have a satisfactory solution is of the bookmark. Presently am using "ratio of present page to the no of pages in the chapter" technique to bookmark. What solution did you come up with ? Pls provide with any idea or code or suggestion(any thing u came upto). I followed your github project too. What was the solution that you came up with ? pls do reply asap

Comment: Hi! I also will be extremely appreciated if you could share you current experience. If you have some working Objective C code we could discuss a commercial cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an approach which might work(not tested yet).
Store the chapter, the page index and the font . When you want to go to that bookmark you change the font twice ( first set the font stored and then the current font ) . The font changes are done while the webview is hidden . There might be a performance issue , although.

Comment: This approach won't update the pageIndex. When rezising the UIWebView the offset will stay the same, which means you maybe aren't on the right page after a new textSize.

Comment: Thought over it again and there is a way to determine the new PageIndex using the rule of three: oldPageIndex * newNumberOfPagesInChapter / oldNumberOfPagesInChapter. For pages per chapter just ask webView.pageCount. (All of this in webViewDidFinishLoad)